# How to implement draw over other app functionality in react native. user should not be able to open other app until he types password

Tags: android, flutter, react-native

I want to create an app that won't allow the user to open any other app until he enters the correct password that he set. My end goal is to create an android application (no matter React Native, Flutter or Android)

I am looking for a react-native library for the same

Answer (score -2):

For flutter, use this plugin. It allows you to show a popup on top of all the apps.

https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window

Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:system_alert_window/system_alert_window.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

///
/// Whenever a button is clicked, this method will be invoked with a tag (As tag is unique for every button, it helps in identifying the button).
/// You can check for the tag value and perform the relevant action for the button click
///
void callBack(String tag) {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  print(tag);
  switch (tag) {
    case "simple_button":
    case "updated_simple_button":
      SystemAlertWindow.closeSystemWindow(prefMode: SystemWindowPrefMode.OVERLAY);
      break;
    case "focus_button":
      print("Focus button has been called");
      break;
    default:
      print("OnClick event of $tag");
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  bool _isShowingWindow = false;
  bool _isUpdatedWindow = false;
  SystemWindowPrefMode prefMode = SystemWindowPrefMode.OVERLAY;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPlatformState();
    _requestPermissions();
    SystemAlertWindow.registerOnClickListener(callBack);
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> _initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      platformVersion = await SystemAlertWindow.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _requestPermissions() async {
    await SystemAlertWindow.requestPermissions(prefMode: prefMode);
  }

  void _showOverlayWindow() {
    if (!_isShowingWindow) {
      SystemWindowHeader header = SystemWindowHeader(
          title: SystemWindowText(text: "Incoming Call", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45),
          padding: SystemWindowPadding.setSymmetricPadding(12, 12),
          subTitle: SystemWindowText(text: "9898989899", fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD, textColor: Colors.black87),
          decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.grey[100]),
          button: SystemWindowButton(text: SystemWindowText(text: "Personal", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45), tag: "personal_btn"),
          buttonPosition: ButtonPosition.TRAILING);
      SystemWindowBody body = SystemWindowBody(
        rows: [
          EachRow(
            columns: [
              EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Some body", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.black45),
              ),
            ],
            gravity: ContentGravity.CENTER,
          ),
          EachRow(columns: [
            EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Long data of the body", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD),
                padding: SystemWindowPadding.setSymmetricPadding(6, 8),
                decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.black12, borderRadius: 25.0),
                margin: SystemWindowMargin(top: 4)),
          ], gravity: ContentGravity.CENTER),
          EachRow(
            columns: [
              EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Notes", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45),
              ),
            ],
            gravity: ContentGravity.LEFT,
            margin: SystemWindowMargin(top: 8),
          ),
          EachRow(
            columns: [
              EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Some random notes.", fontSize: 13, textColor: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD),
              ),
            ],
            gravity: ContentGravity.LEFT,
          ),
        ],
        padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12, top: 12),
      );
      SystemWindowFooter footer = SystemWindowFooter(
          buttons: [
            SystemWindowButton(
              text: SystemWindowText(text: "Simple button", fontSize: 12, textColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 139, 97, 1)),
              tag: "simple_button",
              padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
              width: 0,
              height: SystemWindowButton.WRAP_CONTENT,
              decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.white, endColor: Colors.white, borderWidth: 0, borderRadius: 0.0),
            ),
            SystemWindowButton(
              text: SystemWindowText(text: "Focus button", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.white),
              tag: "focus_button",
              width: 0,
              padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
              height: SystemWindowButton.WRAP_CONTENT,
              decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(
                  startColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 139, 97, 1), endColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 28, 88, 1), borderWidth: 0, borderRadius: 30.0),
            )
          ],
          padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12),
          decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.white),
          buttonsPosition: ButtonPosition.CENTER);
      SystemAlertWindow.showSystemWindow(
          height: 230,
          header: header,
          body: body,
          footer: footer,
          margin: SystemWindowMargin(left: 8, right: 8, top: 200, bottom: 0),
          gravity: SystemWindowGravity.TOP,
          notificationTitle: "Incoming Call",
          notificationBody: "+1 646 980 4741",
          prefMode: prefMode);
      setState(() {
        _isShowingWindow = true;
      });
    } else if (!_isUpdatedWindow) {
      SystemWindowHeader header = SystemWindowHeader(
          title: SystemWindowText(text: "Outgoing Call", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45),
          padding: SystemWindowPadding.setSymmetricPadding(12, 12),
          subTitle: SystemWindowText(text: "8989898989", fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD, textColor: Colors.black87),
          decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.grey[100]),
          button: SystemWindowButton(text: SystemWindowText(text: "Personal", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45), tag: "personal_btn"),
          buttonPosition: ButtonPosition.TRAILING);
      SystemWindowBody body = SystemWindowBody(
        rows: [
          EachRow(
            columns: [
              EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Updated body", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.black45),
              ),
            ],
            gravity: ContentGravity.CENTER,
          ),
          EachRow(columns: [
            EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Updated long data of the body", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD),
                padding: SystemWindowPadding.setSymmetricPadding(6, 8),
                decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.black12, borderRadius: 25.0),
                margin: SystemWindowMargin(top: 4)),
          ], gravity: ContentGravity.CENTER),
          EachRow(
            columns: [
              EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Notes", fontSize: 10, textColor: Colors.black45),
              ),
            ],
            gravity: ContentGravity.LEFT,
            margin: SystemWindowMargin(top: 8),
          ),
          EachRow(
            columns: [
              EachColumn(
                text: SystemWindowText(text: "Updated random notes.", fontSize: 13, textColor: Colors.black54, fontWeight: FontWeight.BOLD),
              ),
            ],
            gravity: ContentGravity.LEFT,
          ),
        ],
        padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12, top: 12),
      );
      SystemWindowFooter footer = SystemWindowFooter(
          buttons: [
            SystemWindowButton(
              text: SystemWindowText(text: "Updated Simple button", fontSize: 12, textColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 139, 97, 1)),
              tag: "updated_simple_button",
              padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
              width: 0,
              height: SystemWindowButton.WRAP_CONTENT,
              decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.white, endColor: Colors.white, borderWidth: 0, borderRadius: 0.0),
            ),
            SystemWindowButton(
              text: SystemWindowText(text: "Focus button", fontSize: 12, textColor: Colors.white),
              tag: "focus_button",
              width: 0,
              padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, top: 10),
              height: SystemWindowButton.WRAP_CONTENT,
              decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(
                  startColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 139, 97, 1), endColor: Color.fromRGBO(247, 28, 88, 1), borderWidth: 0, borderRadius: 30.0),
            )
          ],
          padding: SystemWindowPadding(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 12),
          decoration: SystemWindowDecoration(startColor: Colors.white),
          buttonsPosition: ButtonPosition.CENTER);
      SystemAlertWindow.updateSystemWindow(
          height: 230,
          header: header,
          body: body,
          footer: footer,
          margin: SystemWindowMargin(left: 8, right: 8, top: 200, bottom: 0),
          gravity: SystemWindowGravity.TOP,
          notificationTitle: "Outgoing Call",
          notificationBody: "+1 646 980 4741",
          prefMode: prefMode);
      setState(() {
        _isUpdatedWindow = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isShowingWindow = false;
        _isUpdatedWindow = false;
      });
      SystemAlertWindow.closeSystemWindow(prefMode: prefMode);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('System Alert Window Example App'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Running on: $_platformVersion\n'),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: _showOverlayWindow,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: !_isShowingWindow
                      ? Text("Show system alert window")
                      : !_isUpdatedWindow
                          ? Text("Update system alert window")
                          : Text("Close system alert window"),
                  color: Colors.deepOrange,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```